# distribution of xticks on axis with only two ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

i don't know how to evenly distribute the xticks in a scatterplot with only 2 ticks. I'd really appreciate some help.

Simplyfied the code looks like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

yA = [100,200,300]
yB = [400,500,600]

xA = ['Mitte','Mitte','Mitte']
xB = ['Rand','Rand','Rand']

plt.scatter (xA, yA)
plt.scatter (xB, yB)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: "Picture is of actual non-simplyfied data"]

In the picture the non-simplyfied data is used.

I want the xticks to be evenly distributed along the x-axis.

Really appreciated your help! 
cheers!

Comment: what do you mean with evenly distributed? can you please explain?\

Comment: the distance between y-axis -> xtick 'Mitte' -> xtick 'Rand' -> right boundary should be the same.

Comment: `plt.margins(x=1)`

Comment: sweet, thats it! thanks for the help!